# How can I "read" undocumented AS3 API from source?

Tags: actionscript-3, introspection

What is the best technique for getting at the source code for internal AS3 methods? I'm trying to learn more about DisplayObjectContainer.constructChildren() - is it private? is it protected? can I extend it?

Does such a source view of internal AS3 code exist?

Comment: As far as I know, the source code is not publicly available, so your best resources would be the API and google.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&q=DisplayObjectContainer&btnG=Google+Search#pq=displayobjectcontainer&hl=en&cp=6&gs_id=q&xhr=t&q=adobe+DisplayObjectContainer&qe=YWRvYmUgRGlzcGxheU9iamVjdENvbnRhaW5lcg&qesig=N1nJUtSS40F93mHMTcfBkQ&pkc=AFgZ2tknKCsU2U_KLNoTDrFZZ-syyORE5haL6KhMhPZfmqQXkZbt6mmq5zjdjFHzZoIM6Jn5SxyMfEgwW9wgyMNZKzO59OgnMw&pf=p&sclient=psy&safe=off&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=adobe+DisplayObjectContainer&aq=0v&aqi=g-v1&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=7caaed5eb0414d97&biw=1304&bih=743

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try decompiling the `playerglobal.swc`.  even though it's not always easy to tell what's going on in a decompiled class file (and nearly impossible if the code is obfuscated) you should be able to get an idea of what's happening.

> 1. duplicate then rename `playerglobal.swc` to `playerglobal.zip` and unzip it.
> 2. decompile the `library.swf` file found within the unzipped archive.

you can use one of several commercial Flash decompilers available on the internet.  the one i sometimes use for this purpose is [Trillix](http://www.flash-decompiler.com/) since the free demo will still allow you to read the source files (but you won't be able to highlight/copy the code).

Comment: Nice! Where is this playerglobal.swc file found?

Comment: if you use the Flex SDK:  `sdks > 4.5.1 > frameworks > libs > player > 10.2 > playerglobal.swc`.  if you use Flash Professional:  `Adobe Flash CS5.5 > Common > Configuration > ActionScript 3.0 > FP10.2 > playerglobal.swc`

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell you about viewing the source, but `constructChildren` is not available for override.  The following gives an error in FDT because it cannot see a corresponding method in the superclass:

```
package {
    import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;

    public class Test extends DisplayObjectContainer {

        public function Test():void
        {   
        }

        override protected function constructChildren():void
        {       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for testing this out. I'm not 100% sure it's on DisplayObjectContainer (it seems that that's where it would be) - it might be on Sprite. But you're probably right that it's a private method.

Comment: @Tom - Same results for Sprite.  May I ask why you're looking for this?

Comment: I'm getting frustrated with the way AMF2 builds and instantiates child objects on the display list. They always instantiate before their parent, so if you're relying on design-time elements with exported classes, and those classes want to be able to access initialization values set in their parent, it's a world of trouble to get the timing right. I thought maybe a peek into the code might offer a neat way to change this order or hack a different approach. It's a long shot. A bit of an experiment really.